# proper way to check if a list is empty and raise exception on try: except:

Tags: python, exception

I have a class method that outputs a list of subdirectories of a general directory and I want that function to raise an exception if it's empty (no subdirectories found)

I don't understand the proper way to wrap an empty list check around the try/except block.

```py
def _all_folder_path(self) -> list[Path]:

    export_path: Path = Path(self.export_folder) # This is just "./export-folder"


    export_json_list = [p for p in export_path.iterdir() if p.is_dir()]

    if len(export_json_list) == 0: 
        self._logger.warning(
            f"No folders found on {export_path.stem} folder."
        )
        self.other_funct() # I call another unrelated function to build the sub-dirs 
        self._all_folder_path()

    else:
        self._logger.debug(
            f"Found #{len(export_json_list)} folders on {export_path}"
        )
        return export_json_list
```

Should I remove the list compression and do the try/except on each file?

On this function, I'm not loading anything yet, but rather just building a list of paths.

Comment: `raise Exception("No Files")` ?

Comment: Well yes... I'm dumb. Many thanks!